# calculating limits that include ^(1/x)

Tags: analysis, limits

I am struggling with equations like those:
$$\liminf(1/x)^{1/x}$$
$$\liminf(x)^{1/x}$$
But I am not able to solve them - I always get $$\infty^{0}\;\text{ or }\;0^{0}$$.

Can anybody give me a tip how to deal with stuff like that?

Comment: You take the log of it!

Comment: @KKJ I think it is better to come up with actual exercises you are struggling with, show some effort and share with us where you get stuck

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$(1/x)^{1/x}=e^{(1/x)\ln(1/x)}$$

$$x^{1/x}=e^{(1/x)\ln(x)}$$

Comment: but is not then $$1^{-infinity}$$ and $$1^{infinity}$$? It is the only way of transforming the equations I can see (besides coming back to their basic forms)

Comment: @KKJ my answer is to point out that you should tackle the problem as follows:$$\liminf (1/x)\ln(1/x)\\\liminf x\ln(1/x)$$ and then take e^ of each.